# Comment box label drupal

Tags: forms, drupal-6, comments

I want to change the word "Comment*" which is on the drupal comment form box. Also I want to do this for a specific node type. Actually I want to display different comment box label for each node type.

I read lots of documentary about this. It is said that a theme function or a module which include a hook_form_alter can do that.
But I couldn't find how can I do.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a function like this in you're custom module:

```
MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'comment_form') {
    $node = node_load($form['nid']['#value']);
    if ($node->type == 'SPECIFIC_NODE_TYPE') {
      $form['comment_filter']['comment']['#title'] = "TEXT_YOU_WANT";
    }
  }
}
```